# android.os.Binder.transact() can block UI

Tags: android, user-interface, transactions, locking

I've just received a weird ANR report and looking at the 3 threads involved it's like the transact() method is blocking the UI! Can anyone confirm?

Maybe misleading but tid 23, line ~887 is actually this method:

```
synchronized public void doSomething()
{
   // No sync in here, no API calls either
}
```

Why is this happening ? False report? OS bug? App bug? How can I avoid this in the future?

Just to be clear: main thread is responding to a back button, at android.app.Activity.finish() but blocked by tid=21, tid=21 is an async task calling getApplicationInfo() -> transact()

Here are the stack trace of the 3 threads involved:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 MONITOR
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40aed9a0 self=0x1772cb0
| sysTid=30378 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074254812
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=537 stm=93 core=1
at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:~4138)
- waiting to lock <0x40fa7008> (a my.app.package.activities.tm.at_process_tabs) held by tid=21 (AsyncTask #3)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(SourceFile:175)
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2145)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=23 MONITOR
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41364a68 self=0x1ca4ec0
| sysTid=30749 nice=-1 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=28938832
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at my.app.package.activities.tm.at_process_tabs.a(SourceFile:~887)
- waiting to lock <0x40fa7008> (a my.app.package.activities.tm.at_process_tabs) held by tid=21 (AsyncTask #3)
at my.app.package.activities.tm.x.a(SourceFile:95)
at my.app.package.activities.tm.x.b(SourceFile:1)
at my.app.package.utils.android.d.call(SourceFile:203)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=21 SUSPENDED
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41327370 self=0x1b982a0
| sysTid=30747 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=34484768
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=47 stm=5 core=0
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getApplicationInfo(IPackageManager.j...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is actually quite simple: didn't see it at first, but it was there all along, even though I assumed it was part of the stack trace, very dumb if you ask me as it's in plain English:

```
waiting to lock <0x40fa7008> (a my.app.package.activities.tm.at_process_tabs) held by tid=21 (AsyncTask #3)
```

Funny thing it's easier to read in SO with the nice coloring and formatting than inside ProGuard (my 2 cents excuse for not seeing this).

at_process_tabs is the Activity being terminated by the user, and this method was called by tid 21 and 23:

```
synchronized public at_process_info getProcessInfo(String pid, String process_name)
```

The method was moved (as a convenience method) into the Activity, hence the problem appeared.

Creating an Object to lock on instead of locking this, solved it.